# Exporting shapefile with style settings from QGIS to Google Earth

Tags: qgis, shapefile, export, kml, style

I have a shapefile containing points with circles with specific RGB colors that I am trying to convert to KML to open in Google Earth. In Google Earth, points appear at correct location but instead of circle with color, I only see drop pins. How can I keep my QGIS formatting intact during KML creation?

Comment: You can't. Styles seldomly are cross-plattform.

Comment: Points with circles? Shapefile is a data storage format which only permits point *or* line *or* polygon topology. Symbology is a property of the GIS software, not the geometry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your shapefile contains point-data and you have categorized this points by field in the data-table (see screenshot 1) you can install the [MMQGIS plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mmqgis/) and export als KML file (see screenshot 2).

Result is shown (partially) as screenshot3

screenshot 1:

[image]

screenshot 2:

[image]

screenshot 3:

[image]